# Creating a PropertyOverrideConfigurer that takes values from the Database

Tags: spring, properties, seam

Currently we have a PropertyOverrideConfigurer from Spring that is used to override some values of our configuration, the configuration is then used in Spring and Seam. Now I'd like to create an OverrideConfigurer that uses a DB connection managed by Seam to inject the overridden values into the configuration.

Is there already such a class or am I on my own?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no support from Spring. Probably you need to do it yourself. [This](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1876) link may help you to confirm that you need do it yourself.